# Repair cracked China cymbal?

Tags: drums, repair, drum-kits, drum-hardware

My China cymbal cracked a little while ago and I tried to fix it by drilling holes into the ends of the crack to stop it from spreading through the cymbal, however this doesn't seem to have worked and the crack is spreading. Any ideas on how I could repair it? One of my standard crash cymbals cracked and the fix was to just cut out the cracked section from the side, would that work with a China given its odd shape?

Comment: Can you clarify if you are trying to fix the cymbal back to its original state or just stop cracks from spreading?

Comment: I guess either, if it could be repaired back to rights then great, but if that can't be done then at least stopping it from breaking more would be good

Comment: Please don't link to content on Google Drive or something, but include images right with StackExchange's embedding feature.

Comment: Hi, I've tried doing that but it keeps telling me "something went wrong, try again?"so I linked so I could get my question up while I look into why that was happening, will do next time :)

Comment: i would suggest to send it back to china to get it fixed.